# Opera doesn't show me addressbar content completion for all pages. Why?

Tags: browser, opera, autocomplete, opera-11

When I type something in the address bar then I sometime see Opera offering pages which have the given word in the page text. This would be very useful if it worked all the time, but whenever I try it it fails to show pages which I know I've visited recently and I can clearly remember some words from the page.

Why is is that it only works for some pages? Is there a way to fix it? In its current form this feature is pretty much useless, because sometimes it works, but most often it doesn't.

Comment: Sounds like one of those caching issues. Sometimes it takes a while for it to suggest, sometimes it's instant. Close out and wait for the RAM to free up or the browser to catch up and it works again. Spotty.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [history preferences window](http://help.opera.com/Windows/11.00/en/history.html#preferences) to increase the number of URLs to be remembered. Also make sure that "Remember content on visited pages" is enabled.

> Settings > Preferences > Advanced > History

Comment: It is enabled and the number is set to remember the last 10000 addresses. But the problem is not that it doesn't remember old addresses. It doesn't show me content completion for pages which I visited, say, an hour ago. But when it does show completion then it usually is from some older page which I visited yesterday or a few days ago. The main problem is the feature seems completely random, I can't depend on it, because I never know when it remembers a page and when it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your setting at `opera:config#Addressbar%20Content%20Search` has `Addressbar Content Search` set to enabled/checked. If you don't like the feature as it is, you can simply turn it off there.

When you say it doesn't work all the time, does it show you other pages with the content you're searching for, or not show anything at all? It works fine for me, but sometimes it seems to give higher precedence to "older" pages rather than searching by "last visited" time, which may be what most people would expect. I'm not sure that can be changed, but you could always post a suggestion on the [Opera desktop wishlist forum](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/forum.dml?id=24).

Comment: It is enabled. When I search for something which I know I've read about very recently then it usually shows some older results, but only one or two, so it's not like there is no room for more and newer ones are simply not shown because of the ordering. It seems like it works selectively and only remembers pages it considers important or something. It's a pity, because the feature would be very useful if it worked properly.